# Comparing two arrays in Javascript - Returning differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

Assuming we have:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']; array2 = ['C', 'E'];
```

Is there a proven and fast solution to compare two arrays against each other, returning one array without the values appearing in both arrays (C and E here).
So:

```
array3 = ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

should be the output of the solution. (jquery may be involved)

thx.

Comment: Are the arrays both always sorted, as in your example? If so, this can be done in linear time by just walking the arrays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a set difference.  A simple implementation is:

```
jQuery.grep(array1, function(el)
                    {
                        return jQuery.inArray(el, array2) == -1;
                    });
```

This is O(m * n), where those are the sizes of the arrays.  You *can* do it in O(m + n), but you need to use some kind of hash set.  You can use a JavaScript object as a simple hash set for strings.  For relatively small arrays, the above should be fine.

Comment: Please consider updating this answer to use Array.prototype.filter instead of jQuery.grep since it'll provide a solution even if jQuery is not allowed.

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is indeed a no-library alternative.  However, you need [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) too (instead of inArray).  However, both require loading a polyfill (provided at the links) in older browsers to achieve broad compatibility.

Since the question allowed jQuery, I went with that since it has its own polyfill.

Answer (score 13):

I accepted Matthews Solution, but dont want to ignore a different faster solution i just found.

```
 var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
 var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e'];
 var lookup = {};

 for (var j in list2) {
      lookup[list2[j]] = list2[j];
  }

  for (var i in list1) {
      if (typeof lookup[list1[i]] != 'undefined') {
          alert('found ' + list1[i] + ' in both lists');
          break;
 } 
 }
```

Source: [Optimize Loops to Compare Two Arrays](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/699379-optimize-loops-compare-two-arrays)

Comment: Particularly nice if one of the lists (here list2) needs to be compared to many candidates (many list1's).

Comment: on Chrome, the linked source reference is spotted as containing malware

Answer (score 0):

a proven fast solution that i know of is a binary search that you can use after you sort one of the arrays. so the solution takes time that depends on the sorting algorithm. but is at least log(N).