# Javascript Compare values in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

What would be a shorter way to write :

```
if (array1[0] >= array2[0] && array1[1] >= array2[1] && ...) {
do something;
}
```

I tried creating a function but I was not able to make it work, I'm still quite new at this.

Comment: Refer this link with a similar Question posted <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432929/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript-returning-differences

Comment: @DevendraLattu that question isn't at all similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant way would be to use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
if (array1.every(function(e,i){ return e>=array2[i];})) {
    do something;
}
```

Comment: +1 For the most elegant solution. I deleted my answer which was basically identical, but slower :) .

Comment: I tried this one but I'm getting a syntax error "missing ; before statement".

Comment: Yeah, I'm missing a } here, one sec... Fixed. @user3099816

Answer (score 0):

```
var isGreater = true;
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    if (array1[i] < array2[i])
    {
        isGreater = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isGreater)
{
    //do something
}
```

You loop your first array and replace the numbers by the looping variable (i)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is that *all* elements of of the first are greater than the second, not *some*.

Comment: looking at his example, he was doing arr1[0] vs arr2[0], arr1[1] vs arr2[1], that's what my for loop is doing, he never asked how to check everything with everything

Comment: I disagree. Look at his logic, it's `&&`ing all the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if all elements of `a` are greater than all elements of `b`. It will return as early as possible rather than having to compare all of the elements.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] < b[i]) { return false;}
  }
  return true
 }
```