# how to single out an element in two array's

Tags: javascript

Say I have 2 arrays:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

How do I compare them to single out the element ( in this case the number 4 )?

Something like:

```
 if ( array1 == array2 ) {
    //then do this
 }else{
    // find out the one that isn't the same in each and show it here
 }
```

Comment: simple google search for "javascript array comparison -- find differences reveals this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432929/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript-returning-differences

Comment: what if `var array1 = [1, 2, 3,4];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3];` & `var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [1, 2, 4];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.prototype.find to do the same

check this snippet

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function findNumber(number) { 
    return number=== 4?true:false;
}
var number=array2.find(findNumber);
if(number)
  console.log("found");
else
  console.log("not found");
```

Hope it helps